# Find implicit equation of the following plane parametrized curves

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

I have the following parametrized plane curve: $C_1 =$ Image of $c_1$, where $c_1(t)=(2\cos t,3\sin t)$, and I need to find implicit equation. I don't know exactly what are implicit equation. This exercise is solved in my book and the answare is $C_1:\frac{x(t)^2}{4} + \frac{y(t)^2}{9} = 1$. I don't know why is this the answare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use write the curve in component: $x$ and $y$

Thus:

$\begin{align}
x(t)=2\cos(t)\\
y(t)=3\sin(t)\\
\frac{x(t)}{2}=\cos(t)\\
\frac{y(t)}{3}=\sin(t)\\
\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y(t)}{3}\right)^2=\\
\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=\\
1
\end{align}$

Following the equations, we have just shown that your curve $C$ is described by:

$\begin{equation}
\frac{x(t)^2}{4}+\frac{y(t)^2}{9}=1
\end{equation}$

Comment: Exactly what I need it. Thanks